# Function to delete ALL data attributes, need multi runs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a function which deletes all data attributes (except for the 'data-pauze' attribute). The one i wrote this afternoon kinda works, but doesn't delete all of 'm. I need to run it three times to delete everything.

```js
function removeAllDataAttributes() {
  $('section').each(function(a, b) {
    var section = $(this);
    $.each(this.attributes, function(a, b) {
      if (b !== undefined) {
        var attr = b.name;
        if (attr != 'data-pauze' && !attr.indexOf('data-')) {
          console.log(attr);
          section.removeAttr(attr);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

$('button').click(function() {
  removeAllDataAttributes();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<button>Remove data stuff</button>

<section id="one" data-0="top: 0px;" data-737="top: -737px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="top: 0px;">
  <h1>One</h1>
</section>

<section id="two" data-0="top: 737px;" data-737="top: 0px;" data-1397="top: -660px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="top: 737px;">
  <h1>Two</h1>
</section>

<section id="three" data-pauze="slider" data-0="top: 1397px;" data-1397="top: 0px;" data-7397="top: 0px;" data-7857="top: -460px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="top: 1397px;">
  <h1>Three</h1>
</section>

<section id="four" data-1397="top: 460px;" data-7397="top: 460px;" data-0="top: 1857px;" data-7857="top: 0px;" data-8594="top: -737px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="top: 1857px;">
  <h1>Four</h1>
</section>

<section id="five" data-0="top: 8594px;" data-8594="top: 0px;" data-9331="top: -737px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="top: 8594px;">
  <h1>Five</h1>
</section>

<section id="six" data-pauze="slider" data-0="top: 9331px;" data-9331="top: 0px;" data-15331="top: 0px;" data-16068="top: -737px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="top: 9331px;">
  <h1>Six</h1>
</section>

<section id="seven" data-9331="top: 737px;" data-15331="top: 737px;" data-0="top: 10068px;" data-16068="top: 0px;" data-16805="top: -737px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="top: 10068px;">
  <h1>Seven</h1>
</section>

<section id="eight" data-0="top: 16805px;" data-16805="top: 0px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="top: 16805px;">
  <h1>Eight</h1>
</section>
```

I also made Codepen: http://codepen.io/frankbiemans/pen/VPRdjw.

Dou you guys have any idea what i'm doing wrong? 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you need to delete every `data-` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're modifying the list as you iterate over it.  The index is changing each time you remove an item.  If you have items `0`, `1`, `2` and you remove `1`, `2` no longer exists because the list is now `0`,`1`.  You can quickly solve this by iterating over the list backwards (i.e. `2`, `1`, `0`)

```js
function removeAllDataAttributes() {
  $('section').each(function(a, b) {
    for(var i = this.attributes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var attr = this.attributes[i].name;
      if(attr !== 'data-pauze' && !attr.indexOf('data-')) {
        console.log(attr);
        this.removeAttribute(attr);
      }
    }
  });
}

$('button').click(function() {
  removeAllDataAttributes();
});
```

```css
[data-pauze] {
  color: green;
}

[data-0],
[data-1397],
[data-15331],
[data-16068],
[data-16805],
[data-737],
[data-7397],
[data-7857],
[data-8594],
[data-9331] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<button>Remove data stuff</button>

<section id="one" data-0="top: 0px;" data-737="top: -737px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="top: 0px;">
  <h1>One</h1>
</section>

<section id="two" data-0="top: 737px;" data-737="top: 0px;" data-1397="top: -660px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="top: 737px;">
  <h1>Two</h1>
</section>

<section id="three" data-pauze="slider" data-0="top: 1397px;" data-1397="top: 0px;" data-7397="top: 0px;" data-7857="top: -460px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="top: 1397px;">
  <h1>Three</h1>
</section>

<section id="four" data-1397="top: 460px;" data-7397="top: 460px;" data-0="top: 1857px;" data-7857="top: 0px;" data-8594="top: -737px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="top: 1857px;">
  <h1>Four</h1>
</section>

<section id="five" data-0="top: 8594px;" data-8594="top: 0px;" data-9331="top: -737px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="top: 8594px;">
  <h1>Five</h1>
</section>

<section id="six" data-pauze="slider" data-0="top: 9331px;" data-9331="top: 0px;" data-15331="top: 0px;" data-16068="top: -737px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="top: 9331px;">
  <h1>Six</h1>
</section>

<section id="seven" data-9331="top: 737px;" data-15331="top: 737px;" data-0="top: 10068px;" data-16068="top: 0px;" data-16805="top: -737px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="top: 10068px;">
  <h1>Seven</h1>
</section>

<section id="eight" data-0="top: 16805px;" data-16805="top: 0px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="top: 16805px;">
  <h1>Eight</h1>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the issue is in the using of indexOf as it returnes `-1` if item wasn't not found, so replace `!attr.indexOf('data-')` to `attr.indexOf('data-') == -1` or `!~attr.indexOf('data-')`, where `~` is a bitwise not (`~-1 == 0`).

Comment: Thanks. Didn't try this as a solution but i did understand something was wrong with the "!attr.indexOf('data-')" part and result. I look into it.

Comment: @Chieftain hope it helps you to work with idnexOf :)

Answer (score 0):

(For)each-ing through a collection and deleting the current item is never a good idea, regardless of the language. You're chopping of the branch you're sitting on and that's why your code isn't working as expected.
Create an array (e.g. push the values in the each-loop into some []) and then delete them.

EDIT:
Didn't have much time for a sample yesterday. Here's a generic function to perform what you're after:

```
    function remDataAttributes( item, exceptions ) {
    var arr = [ ];
    $(item).each(function (i)
    {
        $.each(this.attributes, function() {
            if ( this.specified && this.name.startsWith("data-") && $.inArray( this.name.substr( 5 ), exceptions )<0)
                arr.push(this.name);
        });
        var self =$(this);
        arr.forEach(function(e) {
            self.removeAttr(e);
        });
    });
}
```

This function expects a selector specifying the item(s) and an array of exceptions (omit the "data-" part). In your case:

```
remDataAttributes( 'section', [ 'pauze' ] );
```

It's a bit more reusable.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  This is absolutely correct.  The issue is inherently having to do with the index in a `.each()` going from `0` to `n`, where `n` is the length of the collection.  @itlunch can you provide a snippet illustrating how what you proposed would be done in this case?

Comment: Thanks itlunch. Clear explanation. Someone posted going through the array backwards and that worked great but this does sound like a better practice - i'll put it in practice next time.